# what's wrong with my setup on google Oauth? and what is my next action?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

I received an email saying Verification Not Required from Google Cloud Platform.
I have confirmed ownership and refused to use the icon, so I received your email as above.

However, there are still user restrictions in the google cloud console, and it says that verification is required.

Can I provide Google sign-in to customers? What's the next action I should take?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.